# *SwiftUI Beta 7* How to give item in ForEach Loop an active state

Tags: list, select, foreach, swiftui

I have a data model of the type:

```
struct fruit: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var a: String
    var b: String
    var isActive: Bool
}
```

and an array:

```
let fruitData=[
    Model(a:"appleImg", b:"Apple", isActive: true),
    Model(a:"pearImg", b:"Pear", isActive: false),
    Model(a:"bananaImg", b:"Banana", isActive: false),
]
```

There's a RowView that looks like this:

```
struct RowView{
    var a = "appleImg"
    var b = "Apple"
    var isActive = true

    var body: some View{    
      HStack(spacing:8){
         Image(a)
         Text(b)
         Spacer()
      }
   }
}
```

I then created a view to use `ModelArray` in and looped that in a `ForEach` in the main view. So something like:

```
let fruits = fruitData
ForEach(fruits){fruitPiece in
    RowView(a:fruitPiece.a, b:fruitPiece.b, isActive: 
    fruitPiece.isActive)
}
```

I want to change the `isActive` based on the user tapping on the selected row - trick is it should be a single select, so only 1 active state at a time. Still new to SwiftUI so any help is super appreciated :)

Comment: What is the issue? You are not able to find the `index` ? You can't change the array's elements? Properties are constant? Runtime error or build time? or what? Many issues appearing here.

Comment: To be honest, your question *is* vague - at least as to the actual issue. So how about we take `SwiftUI` out of this. You have a great start to your model. And a (pretty) good example, where... let's call it the first element is the only one active. (I'd suggest changing your example to have each element be un pique beyond the `UUID`. Remember, this is only an example.) Now let's say you want the third element in your array to be `isActive = true`. How would you do this? (Hint, this is basic coding, no matter the language.) The problem is, you aren't showing that. (Continued...)

Comment: If you can show us that in your code, then we can being narrowing things down. Now you have... a `List` (be careful, some of us still use `UITableViews` in SwiftUI) and wish to have the user tap the third element and... use your function in your model that's likely an `ObservableObject`? (Hint, this is now using Swift, SwiftUI, and Combine.) Are you having an issue finding which cell/row is being tapped? Or converting that row to find the `UUID`, which likely isn't part of the visible view. Long comments short - which pice of all this is your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below does what you asked. But some comments on your code first:

1. By convention, variable names should never begin with an uppercase (such as in your `let ModelArray`). It makes it harder to read. If not to you, to others. When sharing code (such as in stackoverflow), try to follow proper conventions.
2. You are calling `ForEach(models)`, but you have not defined a models array (you did create ModelArray though).
3. Inside your ForEach, you are calling `Model(...)`. Inside ForEach you need a view to display your data. But Model, in your code, is a data type. Does not make sense.

Here's the code that I think, does what you asked. When you tap the view, its isActive flag toggles. To show that it works, the text color changes accordingly.

```swift
struct Model: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var a: String
    var b: String
    var c: String
    var isActive: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var modelArray = [
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: true),
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(modelArray.indices, id: \.self){ idx in

            Text("\(self.modelArray[idx].a) \(self.modelArray[idx].b) \(self.modelArray[idx].c)")
                .foregroundColor(self.modelArray[idx].isActive ? .red : .green)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.modelArray[idx].isActive = true

                    for i in self.modelArray.indices {
                        if i != idx { self.modelArray[i].isActive = false }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the general tips, some of this I've done in the actual code, but sadly can't share the actual one, so did a quick example to illustrate what I'm trying to do! I managed to do what you've done here, but I'm struggling to make only one of the Text rows red at all times. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Oh, I didn't undestand that last requirement. I modified the code to make the selection exclusive. Bascially, when you tap on any of the rows, you clear the rest. Alternatively, instead of having an isActive flag for each item, you could have a single Int value that indicates which of your rows is the one active. It depends on your needs.